# After captured an image I cant display it on imageview unless i save it in bitmap form. I need save it in Uri form

Tags: android, camera, uri

In my app, when users clicking an imageview, users can choose an image from gallery or capture an image from camera and display it on imageview. I can display the image on imageview if the image is selected from gallery but it failed to display if the image is captured. The imageUri is null if the image is captured.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

There are some codes below, if you need more info please comment below

```
   private final static int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
   private final static int CAMERA = 2;
   private Uri imageUri;

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    public void selectImage() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent();
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }


  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            imageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(circleImageView);
            System.out.println("haha pic " + imageUri);

        }

        if (requestCode == CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){

            imageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(circleImageView);
            System.out.println("haha camera " + imageUri);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you display your image as a bitmap on imageview, after that convert it into url form and store into database.

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

call this method in your `onActivityResult` method and put this code inside

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bitmap = (Bitmap)  extras.get("data");

        circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);
```